# Soundpool load sound A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I have implemented load all sounds in Application onCreate method in background. But when i load sound it gives error like this:

> E/OMXMaster: A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.

What is problem here? Anybody have any idea? Thanks in advance

```
private void loadAllSounds() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            soundPool.load(appContext, R.raw.compose_sound_0, 1);
            soundPool.load(appContext, R.raw.compose_sound_1, 1);
            soundPool.load(appContext, R.raw.compose_sound_2, 1);
            soundPool.load(appContext, R.raw.compose_sound_3, 1);                
        }
    }).start();
}
```